# "fine at your side" vs. "fine on your side"

Tags: grammar, prepositions

What difference(s) do the prepositions below make in the meanings of the following statements:

> I hope things are fine *at* your side.
>
> I hope things are fine *on* your side.

To me the first one rhymes more with the area around the person while the second one with the person itself. What do you think?

Comment: I don’t know what “rhyms more” could possibly mean.  The first sentence doesn’t sound right; I’d have to sleep on it to come up with a possible scenario where it could be used.

Comment: @tchrist- fixed the spelling. Is it inaccurate? I am referring to the use of "rhyme more".

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate, but the "at the side/on the side" issue is discussed some [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66638).

Answer (score 5):

***At your side*** is used when referring to a position immediately to your right or left- as in

> '*My dog was walking **at my side***' or 
>   '*Don't worry I'll be **at your side** the whole time.*'

'***On your side***' or alternatively '*on your end*' is used when discussing location with respect to something like the world or the ocean or it could refer to sides in a game, competition or argument.

***On your end*** can also be used when discussing things over the phone (*your end of the line*) or a business deal (*your end of the deal/bargain*)

Comment: I hear the 'end' case more as '***at*** your end', though.

Comment: @Kris I hear them both about equally I think.

Answer (score 2):

**by someone's side/be on someone's side:** Support

> No one will stand by your side.
>
> Whose side are you on, anyway?

**by the side of/ by someone's side/at someone's side:**
Place (position) closely adjacent to someone

> He looks small by the side of his brother.
>
> She was walking by my side.
>
> He was running at my side.

**at someone's end**:

> How are things at your end?

**NOTE:** *"by someone's side"* has two meanings.

So, *none* of the statements you wrote is correct.
This is the corrected version:

> I hope things are fine at your end.

Answer (score 1):

Both are very unlikely to be said.

I have not been able to think of any example where the first would make sense.

The second could be used in the specific set of circumstances where the the other person is involved in a game, an argument, or a court case: "on your side" would mean "among the people in your team or party".

I suspect that the phrase you want is "at your end", meaning "where you are, as opposed to where I am".

Comment: Is it *at your end or on your end*?

Comment: "at".  Not "on".